# Correct way of Dictionary in a Dictionary Value?

Tags: c#, list, dictionary

I would like to know the most optimal/elegant solution of doing this. Basically i have 3 groups of data.
Each of the groups are inside another in a hierarchy. I'm using a dictionary within a dictionary to achieve this. Sample Code:

```
Dictionary<string,Dictionary<string,List<string>>> pro = new Dictionary<string,Dictionary<string,List<string>>>();
        Dictionary<string,List<string>> part = new Dictionary<string,List<string>>();
        List<string> foo = new List<string>();
        List<string> bar = new List<string>();
        foo.Add("foo1");
        foo.Add("foo2");
        foo.Add("foo3");

        bar.Add("bar1");
        bar.Add("bar2");
        bar.Add("bar3");

        part.Add("Part1", foo);
        part.Add("Part2", bar);
        pro.Add("First", part);

        foreach (var pros in pro)
        {
            foreach (var parts in pros.Value)
            {
                foreach (var foos in parts.Value)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine(foos);
                }
            }
        }
```

I'm still new to c#, even though my code is working i still feel that there is a more elegant solution. Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you could use [collection initializers](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb531208.aspx) for the construction part and [LINQ](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2066496/querying-nested-dictionaries-using-linq) for the print part.

```
Dictionary<string, Dictionary<string,List<string>>> pro = new Dictionary<string, Dictionary<string,List<string>>>()
{
    { "First", new Dictionary<string,List<string>>()
        {
            { "Part1", new List<string>() { "foo1", "foo2", "foo3" } },
            { "Part2", new List<string>() { "bar1", "bar2", "bar3" } }
        }
    }
};
```

EDIT: provided new link for LINQ referring to another useful related post on stackoverflow.

Comment: I like your solution. However, How would i get the list for "Part1"?
pro.["First"]. xxx?

i'm sorry i didn't explain myself clearly. The list is going to be used as a datasource for a listbox.

Comment: you'd write that as pro["First"]["Part1"] to get that list

Comment: Not really the answer i was hoping for, but it helped me find a solution. thanks!

Answer (score 2):

I think you should refactor this kind of code into simple wrapper-classes of Dictionaries. It's almost unreadable this way but if you make a wrapper-class for Parts/Pros, whatever your names are you get niecer looking and reading code and can put some utility functions inside the classes while hiding the implementation-detail of using Dictionaries.

Comment: i understand what you are trying to say, however i have very limited experience. So i'm not quite sure how i would be able to loop in a class.

Comment: So would i make a wrapper class of Pro, make an inner class of Part? and use a List<string> to collect data?

Comment: I don't like inner classes but yes that might be possible (I would just make a *normal* class) - and by either implementing IEnumerable<...> or writing a property of type IEnumerable<...> (... = the type of the things you want to enumerate) you can use foreach(x in classinstance) or foreach(x in classinstance.property)